# How can I use the selected value with Bootstrap Combobox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the plugin of https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/
To make a nice search box with auto complete.

But how do I get the value that was selected?

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class = "form-group">
    <label>Select your name</label>
    <div class="combobox-container">
        <select class="combobox input-large form-control"  id="search_yourself">
            <option></option>
            <?php
                for($row = 0; $row < sizeof($race_table); $row++){
                echo("<option value=".$race_table[$row]['Name'].">".
                $race_table[$row]['Name']."</option>");
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#search_yourself').combobox();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am looking for something like

```
$('#search_yourself').change(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

But instead of `text()` (which returns me all the options, not only the selected one) I need the selected option.

Comment: Couple notes: `<option></option>` should have a `value=""` attribute, and avoid using `alert(...);` for debugging. Try to use `console.log(...);`

Comment: These notes are appreciated, I don't have a developer background so all help is welcome.

Comment: No problem! Also, do you know how to use your browser's development tools? `F12` in Chrome or Firefox, in this case you want the `Console` tab so view any `console.log(...);` statements.

Comment: Yes this I know. How come it didn't work with alert, but it does work with console.log() ?

Comment: Alert flashes something to your screen, but could be blocked by browser settings (I think?) `console.log(...);` is just a better choice all around.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#search_yourself').change(function() {
            alert( $('#search_yourself option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: With alert it doesn't work, but with console.log this worked!

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek Now did it log `""` and then `"Selected Value"` (or whatever the value is) or is that just me?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#search_yourself').change(function() {
            alert( $(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. Is there maybe another event rather than change I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#search_yourself').change(function() {
         alert("Value:" + $(this).val());
         alert("Text:" + $(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The library adds a hidden input with the same 'name' attribute like the original select. This input gets updated by the library so you can get the desired option value by selecting this input by the 'name' attribute.

```
<select id="add-holiday" class="custom_holiday" name="add-holiday">
<option value="">Enter Holiday</option>
<option value="1">President's Day</option>
<option value="2">Christmas</option>
<option value="3">Memorial Day</option>
</select>
```

Get the value by attribute 'name' (via jquery)

```
$("input[name='add-holiday']").val();
```